# Nginx http to https redirection on localhost giving page redirection error

Tags: nginx

I have hosted a simple static site on localhost on Nginx in Ubuntu. But the redirection code is giving me error "Page isn't redirecting properly".

The redirecting code providing problem is:

```
return                301 https://$host$request_url;
```

I am referring the [official docs](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/how-to-configure-nginx).

My Nginx code is given below.

[image]

The procedure to generate error is:

a. If no redirecting code i.e. "return 301 https://$host$request_url;". Then on opening "https://localhost" works good. While http://localhost does not work.

b. I add redirect code so that http gets redirected to https. But it gives me "Page isn't redirecting properly". Here "http://localhost" does redirects to "https://localhost" but page isn't redirecting properly comes. See below image:

[image]

How to solve it?

Comment: You might want to edit the question to make it easier to help, in particular including the code as text instead of an image. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Nginx code you're replying to an HTTPS request with a 301. You need another section where HTTP requests reply with the 301 redirecting to HTTPS.

That is, a second `server { ... }` block which listens on port 80, and that one is the one which redirects, not the one listening on port 443.

You basically created a loop where HTTPS requests redirect to themselves.

Sometimes wrongly set cookies create this kind of loop which is why the browser is hinting at that.

Comment: Ok understood but according to the docs they wrote - "Thanks to the return 301 line in the above configuration, anyone visiting the site on port 80 via an HTTP URL will get automatically redirected to the equivalent secure HTTPS URL.". Have they wrote wrong ?

Comment: I have tested your answer by putting second server block. It worked. Thank you. It seems they wrote the docs incorrectly.

Comment: @yogihosting Yes, that configuration block from the [Ubuntu docs](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/how-to-configure-nginx) doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @yogihosting BTW, the official docs for Nginx are at https://nginx.org/en/docs/. The Ubuntu Docs are partially community-written.